# Pandas no me lee un csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo.csv con Python usando pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


datos = pd.read_csv('INAH_detallado_2019.csv', sep=',')
print(datos)
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el script me aparece esto :

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

el archivo es así:

```
Estado,Clave SIINAH,Siglas,Centro de trabajo,A�o,Mes,Tipo de visitantes,N�mero de visitas,Nacionalidad
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Estudiantes nivel b�sico,527,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Entrada dominical,617,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Boleto pagado,19,Extranjeros
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Estudiantes nivel superior,188,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Boleto pagado,80,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Exposiciones temporales con costo adicional,0,Extranjeros
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Trabajadores INAH,0,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,"Tercera edad, pensionados y jubilados",96,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Exposiciones temporales con costo adicional,0,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Entrada sin costo,1,Extranjeros
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Profesores,79,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Discapacitados,3,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,1,Entrada sin costo,166,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,2,Estudiantes nivel b�sico,542,Nacional
Aguascalientes,2300100,M.- M.H,Museo Regional de Historia de Aguascalientes,2019,2,Entrada dominical,812,Nacional
```

Tiene más lineas pero así es su estructura.

Gracias, si me pueden ayduar.

Comment: El error te indica que el archivo está vacío o no ha podido parsear ninguna columna con el separador. A veces los archivos de texto en Windows añaden caracteres extra o tienen una codificación diferente. Vuelve a generar el archivo .csv o prueba a importar tu archivo a una hoja de cálculo para asegurarte que tiene el formato correcto

Comment: Puede que sea un problema del ```enconder``` mira el formato en el que se encuentra tu csv (utf-8, latin-1, etc) y usa el parámetro ```enconder``` dentro de ```read_csv()``` marcando el formato de tu csv.

Comment: con 'latin-1' me sirvio, pero también me toco crear un ambiente virtual e instalar pandas en el env y así si corre.